# Mongoose query doesn't execute properly, no error message

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Here's my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostsSchema = new Schema({
    userId: String,
    postId: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    tags: { many: String, where: String, what: String }, 
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
}, { collection : 'posts'});

const Posts = mongoose.model('Post', PostsSchema);

module.exports = Posts;
```

Here's my route with the query:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Posts = require('../models/Posts');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
const refreshOrLoadMore = params.refreshOrLoadMore || '';
if (refreshOrLoadMore === 'loadMore') {
        console.log('1');
        Posts.find({}).sort({date:-1}).limit(10, (err, data) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log('2');
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                console.log('3');
                res.json(data);
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

The if statement returns true and the first console.log is triggered. But after that none of the other console.logs are triggered and just nothing happens. No data is being send and no error is being send.

So my guess is, that i did something wrong with the Schema, but i did it just as i did my other ones and they do work.

Can someone point out where i went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if (refreshOrLoadMore === 'loadMore') {
        console.log('1');
        Posts.find({}).sort({date:-1}).limit(10) 
         .exec((err, data) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log('2');
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                console.log('3');
                res.json(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thank you, that did work :D

Is there a reason why the callback in my version doesn't work? The mongoose documentation says, that both versions should work